# What will be the output of this python snippet? And why?

Tags: python

```
a = '1'
b = "11"
print(a + b)
```

The output of this code is "11". Can somebody explain me how?

Comment: Except it isn't...

Comment: Check it again. It should be "111". Then, read about string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = '1'
b = "11"
print(a + b)
```

Output:

```
111
```

Since you are concaticating 2 string: `"11"+"1" =111`